# Python - Write JSON List to Mongo DB

Tags: python

My script gets a response from a websocket, the response contains dicts and a list, I need the list. I then need to save the list to a mongodb. I though I though I could use dict(zip) to convert the list to a dict but I get this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

code:

```
import json, time
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from websocket import create_connection

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    db_name = 'KTDB'
    db_collect = 'crypto_data'
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    mydb = client[db_name]   
    
    ws = create_connection("wss://ws.kraken.com/") 
    ws.send(json.dumps({
        "event": "subscribe",
        "pair": ["BTC/USD"],
        "subscription": {"name": "trade"}
    }))

    timeout = time.time() + 60*1

    while time.time() < timeout:
        
        js = json.loads(ws.recv())
          
        if isinstance(js, list): 
            print(js)      

            jd = zip(range(len(js)), js)                

            #jd=dict(zip(js,range(len(js))))
            mydb[db_collect].insert_many(jd) 
            #mydb[db_collect].insert_one({"test": 'check'})
```

the ws response:

```
[321, [['47426.40000', '0.01799527', '1613158549.286001', 's', 'l', '']], 'trade', 'XBT/USD']
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I get this error: `TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is fundamentally a key/value pair store. It can store lists, but only as the value half of the key/value pair.

So to achieve your objective of storing a list, create a key (dict) and store the list as a value.

```
if isinstance(js, list):
    mydb[db_collect].insert_one({'my_list': js})
```